# $m ( \{ x : f(x) > 0 \} ) = 0 \implies f = 0 $ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $f$ is non-negative measurable function. Put $E = \{ x : f(x) > 0 \} $.

Say $m(E) = 0$. In other words, $E$ is null set. Then does it follow that $f = 0 $ almost everywhere ?

Comment: What is your definition of "almost everywhere"?

Comment: Except on a null set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $f$ is zero except on the null set $E$, which means that it is zero almost everywhere. Indeed, for every real $x \notin E$ (that is, $f(x) \not > 0$) we must have $f(x) = 0$ because $f(x)$ is assumed to be non-negative.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there is a set $F$ of positive measure where $f>0$. Then $E \supset F$, and therefore $m(E)>0$.

Of course, the conclusion is false if $f$ can change sign.